# Is there any way to restrict touch inputs to a panel in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement swipe controls in my game and want the swipes to be detected only on the left side of the screen and leave the other control mechanism of the game as is.

I'm using this `SwipeManager`:

```
public enum Swipes { None, Up, Down, Left, TopLeft, BottomLeft, Right, TopRight,  BottomRight};

public class SwipeManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float minSwipeLength = 200f;

    private Vector2 fingerStart;
    private Vector2 fingerEnd;

    public static Swipes direction;
    public static float angle;
    public static Vector2 strength;

    public static bool debugMode = false;

    void Update ()
    {
        SwipeDetection();
    }

    public void SwipeDetection ()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            fingerStart = Input.mousePosition;
            fingerEnd  = Input.mousePosition;
        }

        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
            fingerEnd = Input.mousePosition;

            strength = new Vector2 (fingerEnd.x - fingerStart.x, fingerEnd.y - fingerStart.y);

            // Make sure it was a legit swipe, not a tap
            if (strength.magnitude < minSwipeLength) {
                direction = Swipes.None;
                return;
            }

            angle = (Mathf.Atan2(strength.y, strength.x) / (Mathf.PI));
            if (debugMode) Debug.Log(angle);
            // Swipe up
            if (angle>0.375f && angle<0.625f) {
                direction = Swipes.Up;
                if (debugMode) Debug.Log ("Up");
                // Swipe down
            } else if (angle<-0.375f && angle>-0.625f) {
                direction = Swipes.Down;
                if (debugMode) Debug.Log ("Down");
                // Swipe left
            } else if (angle<-0.875f || angle>0.875f) {
                direction = Swipes.Left;
                if (debugMode) Debug.Log ("Left");
                // Swipe right
            } else if (angle>-0.125f && angle<0.125f) {
                direction = Swipes.Right;
                if (debugMode) Debug.Log ("Right");
            }
            else if(angle>0.125f && angle<0.375f){
                direction = Swipes.TopRight;
                if (debugMode) Debug.Log ("top right");
            }
            else if(angle>0.625f && angle<0.875f){
                direction = Swipes.TopLeft;
                if (debugMode) Debug.Log ("top left");
            }
            else if(angle<-0.125f && angle>-0.375f){
                direction = Swipes.BottomRight;
                if (debugMode) Debug.Log ("bottom right");
            }
            else if(angle<-0.625f && angle>-0.875f){
                direction = Swipes.BottomLeft;
                if (debugMode) Debug.Log ("bottom left");
            }
        }

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
            direction = Swipes.None;  
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create a panel on the left of the screen and want the swipes to be detected only on the panel, anywhere clicked outside that panel (i.e. on the right side of the screen) should not be considered a swipe but to target (as it is set up now)

Thanks

Comment: Maybe ask on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to skip `SwipeDetection` when the mouse pointer is outside of the panel. So, if you can get a reference to the panel's `RectTransform`, then you can just check if the mouse pointer is inside of it before you call `SwipeDetection`.

In order to account for the possibility of the user pressing out of the panel then moving into it, you could assign `fingerStart = Input.mousePosition;` when the mouse is outside of the rect.

Altogether, this might look like:

```
public RectTransform rectTransform; // panel RectTransform assigned to this variable

...

void Update ()
{
    Vector2 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;

    if (RectTransformUtility.RectangleContainsScreenPoint(rectTransform, mousePosition))
    {
        SwipeDetection();
    }
    else 
    {
        fingerStart = Input.mousePosition;
        direction = Swipes.None;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. I did as suggested, edited the ``SwipeManager.cs`` script to include the rect transform and dragged my panel into it in the inspector. Then I wrapped the ``SwipeDetection()`` function in the if block given by you. But it does not seem to follow it, the swipe is still detected anywhere on the screen.

Comment: @StuckInPhD Try that edit. The code I had in before assumed the panel's parent covered the whole screen.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you. I'll accept the answer as my initial problem has been solved. I am using these swipes to change lanes of attack, there are 4 lanes, and another issue I am facing is that a single swipe is not considered a single swipe but a many lanes are changed and cycled around in a single swipe. Is there any way to contain a single swipe to a single action? rather than a continuous series of swipes.? Many Thanks

Comment: @StuckInPhD I would add code in your lane changer to have a flag like `bool alreadySwipe = false;`. When you detect swipe, check `alreadySwipe`. If `alreadySwipe` is `true`, don't do anything. If it is `false`, do the lane change and set `alreadySwipe = true;`. Whenever `SwipeManager.direction == Swipes.None` put `alreadySwipe = false;` again. Also note that I added `direction = Swipes.None;` to my answer.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. It makes sense and I'll add it to my code. But I dont follow your last line, you said that I should note that you added ``direction = Swipes.None;`` to your answer. But I cant see it in your updated answer. Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: @StuckInPhD That's weird, I guess I didn't properly save my changes. I put it back in now.